# description for dll files

Tags: c#

hi how to find description for a class in a dll file. in my project i use  diff calss in imagealg.dll tell me how to find description for that.plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to find a description for the class is in the documentation.

Comment: k but how to get documentation  where it is plz tell me

Comment: From where did you get the assembly (dll file)?

Answer (score 0):

I i am right you want the documentation from the class like one shown by visual studio when you hover over a class. If that is the cas. You can only find the description about the class if it has been properly [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) by developer . Then you can see the description when you hover your mouse over the class or Right-click on the class and select GoTo Definition , it will take you to a full code definitions extracted from meta data. There also you can see the XML summary documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you have that dll referenced in your project, go to Object Explorer and if you have your classes in referencing assembly properly commented you should see those comments in Object explorer

Use comments like this so they will be visible in your Object Browser.

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the content of

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
```

As far as i know this is not compiled into the dll but put into an additional xml-file if you check the "Generate Xml-Documentation" under your projects build option

Answer (score -1):

right click the solution explorer and select AddReference and add your dll.

In your code

```
      Imagealg.Class1 will bring all the public classes inside the dll
```

Comment: if he is using the dll's class that means obviously he has added a reference to the dll.