# how to read description for the code

Tags: c#

hi i send some c# code this is get from imagealg.dll file the class name is diff code is given below how to get description for this code.

```
public sealed class Diff
{
// Fields
private int diff;
private Bitmap overlayImage;
private Bitmap overlayImage1;

// Methods
public Diff()
{
}

public Diff(Bitmap overlayImage, Bitmap overlayImage1)
{
    this.overlayImage = overlayImage;
    this.overlayImage1 = overlayImage1;
}

public int Apply(Bitmap srcImg, Bitmap dstImg)
{
    int width = srcImg.Width;
    int height = srcImg.Height;
    int num3 = dstImg.Width;
    int num4 = dstImg.Height;
    PixelFormat format = (srcImg.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) ? PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed : PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
    BitmapData data = srcImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, format);
    BitmapData ovrData = dstImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, num3, num4), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, format);
    this.ProcessFilter(data, ovrData, format);
    dstImg.UnlockBits(ovrData);
    srcImg.UnlockBits(data);
    return this.diff;
}

public void ApplyInPlace(Bitmap img)
{
    int width = img.Width;
    int height = img.Height;
    if (((img.PixelFormat != this.overlayImage.PixelFormat) || (width != this.overlayImage.Width)) || (height != this.overlayImage.Height))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    if ((img.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) && (img.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    BitmapData bitmapdata = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    img.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);
}

public int difference()
{
    return this.diff;
}

private unsafe void ProcessFilter(BitmapData data, BitmapData ovrData, PixelFormat fmt)
{
    int width = data.Width;
    int height = data.Height;
    int num3 = (fmt == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) ? 1 : 3;
    int num4 = width * num3;
    int num5 = data.Stride - num4;
    byte* numPtr = (byte*) data.Scan0.ToPointer();
    byte* numPtr2 = (byte*) ovrData.Scan0.ToPointer();
    this.diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int num8 = 0;
        while (num8 < num4)
        {
            int num6 = numPtr[0] - numPtr2[0];
            string str = Convert.ToString(numPtr[0]);
            string str2 = Convert.ToString(numPtr2[0]);
            if (num6 != 0)
            {
                this.diff++;
            }
            num8++;
            numPtr++;
            numPtr2++;
        }
        numPtr += num5;
        numPtr2 += num5;
    }
}

// Properties
public Bitmap OverlayImage
{
    get
    {
        return this.overlayImage;
    }
    set
    {
        this.overlayImage = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you put that question in proper English please?

Comment: You seem to have some trouble with English. I would suggest writing your question in your native language and then using an online translator (hopefully one exists for your language.) It will not be perfect but will probably work better than what is above. We have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524321/description-for-dll-files) you've recently received and/or been asked to use a library containing code that you don't quite understand. Unfortunately, if the source isn't properly documented, you only have two choices:

1. Go back to whomever or wherever you got the code from and ask them for proper documentation. Every piece of source code that you receive should come with documentation.
2. Study the code carefully and try to figure out what it's doing and how you are supposed to use it. This is somewhat closer to "reverse-engineering" the library (except that you have the source), and it's usually reserved as a last-ditch effort.

   In fact, if any of us were to try and answer this question, that's all we could do is read and interpret the code you've posted. Is there something *specific* that you don't understand and are seeking clarification about?

And finally, remember this as a lesson to yourself. Whenever you write code, make sure that you take the time to document it properly so you don't put someone else who tries to use your code in the same situation that you're in now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be happy to know that the code doesn't do anything particularly significant.  The `Apply` method sets up and calls `ProcessFilter`, which does a comparison of the two images and returns a count of the number of pixels that differ between the two.

The `ApplyInPlace` method does nothing.

And I feel sorry for the poor programmer who inherits this code and has to maintain it, what with all those useful variable names like `num4` and `num6`.

It is my fondest wish that the programmer who brought this abomination into the world has been permanently banned from ever touching another keyboard.